# Regex expression to match alternating characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a string of numbers and detect if there's a pattern of alternating digits. For example, `3131` is a match. `4596961` is a match because it contains `9696`. `433215` is not a match because there are not alternating digits.

The current expression I've written is `/(\d)(\d)(\\1\\2)+/` and it works well *EXCEPT* it also matches repeated consecutive digits. For example, it matches 5555, when I don't want it to because 5555 is not made of alternating digits (not-strictly speaking at least).

**Essentially, I'd like to tell the Regex engine that the first `\d` and the second `\d` are to be different characters.**

How do I do this?

Comment: What engine/flavor do you use ?

Comment: I'm using this in PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(\1\2)+/
```

Also, you only need one backslash for your escape sequences if you use `'...'` strings:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/(\d)  # Match a digit and store it in group number 1
    (?!\1)  # Assert that the next char is not the same as the one in group 1
    (\d)    # Match a digit, store it in group 2
    (\1\2)+ # Match one or more repetitions of the two digits matched previously
    /x', 
    $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Comment: Whether one or two backslashes are necessary depends on the environment. For instance, `"`-delimited strings in PHP would require both `/` at the ends and double backslashes.

Comment: @m.buettner: OK, but if he was using that, his mix of single and double escapes wouldn't have worked, would it?

Comment: I think it would have, because `\d` is not a valid escape sequence, so the `\ ` remains a literal character.

Comment: Yes, I am using this in PHP so I need the two `\\`. Also, @TimPietzcker can you explain what you did there?

Comment: @Imray: there is a better solution than double backslashes (single quotes, see Tim's updated answer)

Comment: btw, I just realised: in all of our patterns: the `+` is completely redundant

Comment: @m.buettner: That's true, unless he wants to find out how many repetitions there are.

Answer (score 3):

If your regex flavor supports negative lookaheads, you could ensure, that the second digit is not the same as the first:

```
/(\d)(?!\\1)(\d)\\1\\2/
```

This makes sure that the initial `(\d)` is not followed by the same thing again.

By the way, just an idea to shorten the pattern:

```
/((\d)(?!\\2)\d)\\1/
```

Whether that's more easily readable or not is your call.

Comment: In the second pattern shouldn't the `1` and `2` be the other way around? The first back-reference referring to the `(\d)` matchgroup the second referring to the entire two digit pattern?

Comment: @bmorris591 that's the way it is. Backreferences are counted by opening parentheses from left to right.